# Why is my WordPress visual editor not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have website running WordPress 4.6.2 and I can't use the visual editor right now, only the text editor. When I open the browser console it show various errors.

I've been working on this problem for a good few hours and tried:

- restoring WordPress
- deactivating plugins
- deactivate the custom CSS used in the site
- Looking for `can_compress_scripts` in the DB and all various stuff that I stumble upon internet but with no success whatsoever
- Used theme is Spacious
- Include `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);` into wp-config.php
- Replaced TinyMCE folder content with TinyMCE content from clear installation
- A screenshot of the error from my web browser's console (below):
  [image: Error from my web browser's console]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried to upload photo with console errors but it didnt work. Here is a screenshot [link](http://i.imgur.com/MnLOR0z.jpg)

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes! How can one tell why your code isn't working and possibly provide an effective fix without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Please consider updating your post to include as much details so as to enable the community truly understand the nature of your challenge.

Comment: I see. I tried to describe the problem as simple and clear as I can and provide as much info as I can. Unfortunately there isn't clear info what caused the problem, there isn't much more to describe the nature of the problem more than "visual editor doesn't work". I tried to explain what I do in the original post. Sorry I'm new here, tried to read few posts in order to structure my own :)

Comment: Do you get the same error when you switch your theme to any of the shipped core WordPress one (let's say twentyseveteen theme)?

Comment: Yes I see the same problem when I switch to Twenty Fifteen. Also I tried to delete the theme Spacious, clean install it but with no success whatsoever. Is it possible to reinstall wordpress without bugging the site. This is the site [link](http://raitz-2.com)

Comment: By "bugging" I think you meant without a down time I guess! I do not see the same errors in console. I think you should first completely backup your site, then do a replicate of if so as to look closer to the problem without any potential adverse damage. Did you perform any edits of prior to the error and or any updates? Any possible clue to what the source/origin of the problem might have been?

Comment: Tried to remove Wordpress installation, made new one and then restored the site via Softaculous. The fresh installation had working visual editor, after restore visual editor was bugged again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently deleting few plugins solved the problem. The weird thing is that the problematic plugins were YoastSEO and Akismet and even after their reinstall i got tons of errors too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround or possibly the solution if you dont want to go deep into codes.

This is the fix: (It worked in my case and I am sure it can work for others with similar issue.)

1. Install Visual Composer(Wpbackery or others)
2. Go to => Role manager => Post type => custom => Select both for post and page.

That's all.

I found this workaround that is very good and can work in other case after running into this case where I could not switch from visual editor to text editor on wordpress.
I simply adjusted my WPbackery setting and everything works fine now on my site.

Before then I had tried so many solutions and even included `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS',`  to my config but to no avail.

I don't know if there is the need to explain all the things I have done on the cause of troubleshooting for this for a whole day. But with the solution I posted above it would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by installing the TinyMCE Advanced Plugin, then hitting save so the settings took effect and it worked.